# Creating different models for a view in Backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I've an web application written using Backbonejs which consists of two modes 
`1. Read`
`2. Edit`
I have a `view` and a corresponding `model` associated with it.
Following is the behaviour, I'm trying to achieve

1. Not all properties of `model`, I'm going to show in the `read mode`
2. All properties of `model` will be shown in `edit mode`
3. The view is being given some additional responsibility in edit mode which is being achieved using `mixin`
4. I do not want to bring extra information in `read mode`
5. I do not want my `server side` logic to know whether the application is in read or edit mode

Do someone thinks that creating two seperate `models` for a `view` depending upon `mode` and creating  altogether different `service` will solve my issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is the same model's information you are trying to work with, you will need a Read View and an Edit View, but can use the same model and be selective about the attributes you want to deal with in either of these views

Comment: I'm not changing the view associated with model but giving it additional properties through mixin in edit mode.